# Scilab plot shows incorrect ode values

Tags: function, plot, graph, ode, scilab

I'm trying to create a model of an asynchronous electrical motor in scilab, and display graphs of how the rpm, currents and torque change over time. It looks quite long but you don't need to read it all.

```
fHz = 50;   
Um = 230;
p = 3;
we = 2*%pi*fHz/p; 
wb = 2*%pi*50; 
Rs = 0.435; 
Rr = 0.64; 
Ls = 0.0477;
Xls = wb*Ls; // [Ohm] 
Lr = 0.0577;
Xlr = wb*Lr; // [Ohm]
Lm = 0.012;
Xm = wb*Lm; // [Ohm]
Xml = 1/(1/Xls + 1/Xm + 1/Xlr) // [Ohm];
D = 0.0002;
J = 0.28;
Mt = 0.0;

function [xdot]=AszinkronGep(t, x, Um, fHz)

xdot = zeros(12, 1);

Fsq = x(1);
Fsd = x(2);
Frq = x(3);
Frd = x(4);
wr = x(5);
isabc(1) = x(6);
isabc(2) = x(7);
isabc(3) = x(8);
irabc(1) = x(9);
irabc(2) = x(10);
irabc(3) = x(11); 

Ua = Um*sin(2*%pi*fHz*t);
Ub = Um*sin(2*%pi*fHz*t - 2*%pi/3);
Uc = Um*sin(2*%pi*fHz*t + 2*%pi/3);

Uab = 2/3*[1, -0.5, -0.5; 0, sqrt(3)/2, -sqrt(3)/2]*[Ua;Ub;Uc];

phi = 2*%pi*fHz*t;
Udq = [cos(phi), sin(phi); -sin(phi), cos(phi)]*Uab;
Usd = Udq(1);
Usq = Udq(2);
Urd = 0;
Urq = 0;

isd = ( Fsd-Xml*(Fsd/Xls + Frd/Xlr) )/Xls;
isq = ( Fsq-Xml*(Fsq/Xls + Frq/Xlr) )/Xls;
ird = ( Frd-Xml*(Fsd/Xls + Frd/Xlr) )/Xlr;
irq = ( Frq-Xml*(Fsq/Xls + Frq/Xlr) )/Xlr;

isdq = [isd; isq];
isalphabeta = [cos(phi), -sin(phi); sin(phi), cos(phi)]*isdq;
isabc = [1, 0; -0.5, sqrt(3)/2; -0.5, -sqrt(3)/2]*isalphabeta;

irdq = [ird; irq];
iralphabeta = [cos(phi), -sin(phi); sin(phi), cos(phi)]*irdq;
irabc = [1, 0; -0.5, sqrt(3)/2; -0.5, -sqrt(3)/2]*iralphabeta;

//TORQUE
Me = (3/2)*p*(Fsd*isq - Fsq*isd)/wb

Fmq = Xml*( Fsq/Xls + Frq /Xlr );
Fmd = Xml*( Fsd/Xls + Frd /Xlr );

//Differential equations
xdot(1) = wb*( Usq - we/wb*Fsd + Rs/Xls*(Fmq - Fsq) );
xdot(2) = wb*( Usd + we/wb*Fsq + Rs/Xls*(Fmd - Fsd) );
xdot(3) = wb*( Urq - (we - wr)/wb*Frd + Rr/Xlr *(Fmq - Frq) );
xdot(4) = wb*( Urd + (we - wr)/wb*Frq + Rr/Xlr *(Fmd - Frd ) );
xdot(5) = p*(Me - D*wr - Mt)/J; 
xdot(6) = isabc(1);
xdot(7) = isabc(2);
xdot(8) = isabc(3);
xdot(9) = irabc(1);
xdot(10) = irabc(2);
xdot(11) = irabc(3);
xdot(12) = Me;

if t <= 5 then
disp(Me);  
end

endfunction


//Simulation parameter
t = 0:0.001:5;
t0 = 0;

//Starting parameters
y0 = [0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0]
y = ode(y0,t0,t,list(AszinkronGep,Um,fHz));  

//Graphs
figure(1)
plot(t,y(5,:), "linewidth", 3);
xlabel("time [s]", "fontsize", 3, "color", "blue");
ylabel("rpm [rpm]", "fontsize", 3, "color", "blue");

figure(4)
plot(t,y(12,:), "linewidth", 3);
xlabel("time [s]", "fontsize", 3, "color", "blue");
ylabel("torque [Nm]", "fontsize", 3, "color", "blue");
```

I want a graph that shows 'Me' as a function of time. So I write: xdot(12) = Me, then plot that, but it doesn't looks like how it should at all. Just to check, I added 'disp(Me)' at the end of the function, to see if the calculations are correct at all. And yes, those are the right values. Why does it give me different values when I plot it?

Comment: Perhaps because `y(12)` is the integral over `Me`, and not `Me` itself?

Comment: Hmm, so how should I do it correctly?If I try plot(t,Me) it says 'undefined variable'. I guess that's because 'Me' is defined inside the function.

Comment: You could also evaluate the ODE function `xdot=AszinkronGep(t, x, Um, fHz)` on the computed states of the solution and extract the `Me` values from `xdot(12)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `y(12)` is the integral of `Me` over `t`.
If you want `Me`, you just need to differentiate it:

```
//after you run ode() and have y values
h = t(2) - t(1);
Me = diff(y(12,:)) ./ h;

//plotting
scf(); clf();

subplot(2,1,1);
xtitle("y(12,:)");
plot2d(t,y(12,:));

subplot(2,1,2);
xtitle("Me");
plot2d(t(1:$-1),Me);
```

Here is the output:

[image: 1]

Comment: That looks exactly like it should! Can you clarify how you achieved the plot? I still get empty an empty graph when I try to plot it. On a slightly related note, I have the same problem with x(6) - x(11), with the difference that in that case, the form of the function is correct, just not the amplitudes. Do I need to differentiate it the same way?

Comment: @Fifmut I just edited my answer. Check the code again. Note that I used ``t(1:$-1)``, where ``$`` means last index, because ``diff()`` decreases by one the length of ``y(12,:)``. Also, I dislike using ``plot()``, which exists for compatibility with MATLAB. I always use ``plot2d()``.

Comment: I have used your method and got all the correct values.You have no idea how much you helped me, thank you!